# BSC or Ethereum transaction history

Tags: ethereum, bsc

I am thinking of one thing for the transaction history data. Whether there is an API call, maybe RPC call or REST call, that we can query target wallet address transaction history? I am trying for making a wallet, I think if we can show users their transaction history, it is a good feature for the user experience.
For this question, there are maybe some ways:

1. Call Bcsscan or Ethereumscan API, directly.
2. Start your own server, subscribe to all events, and store them to DB and query events in DB.
   Any other good ideas for this feature.

Answer (score 1):

For method 2) Currently to extract the full address interaction history you need to walk through all blockchain blocks and then all transactions in those using [EVM tracing](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/dapp/tracing).

For method 1) You can also get some details over Etherscan API, but please note that this is not an open-source product and you need to contact their paid product support to understand what data is available over their API and what are the API limitations.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, seems paid is a good choice.